# Two columns paragraph layout by using html and CSS.?

Tags: html, css

I'm learning HTML/CSS and came up with the problem of creating a two columns layout.
but in this specific task, at the left, I have added an image (which is totally random) and at the right, I have a dummy paragraph. And above these two columns, I want a text to be written in the center (by center, I mean the center of the parent element).
I don't know what's the problem here. I have done some changes in the code too, but now the image I used is not showing up completely and also the upper text moved to the right but I want it to be in the center.
You can check my code and kindly specify the where the problem is. THANKS.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#outer {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  border: 3px solid maroon;
  height: 400px;
  clear: both;
}

p {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

#bg {
  background-image: url(downloaded.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

#inner {}
```

```html
<h1>THE BACKGROUND PROPERTY</h1>
<div id="outer">
  It is fun to play with CSS elements.
  <p id="bg">
  </p>
  <p id="inner">
    In this lecture we're going to talk about positioning elements by floating them. Now knowing how to properly float elements is an essential skill to have, and this is partially because most of the UIs today, web UIs today that are made, are made by floating
    the elements. In fact, by the end of this lecture, we're going to create a two column flexible design where the columns will be flexible as we expand and contract the browser. So let's jump into the code editor and see how this works. Okay, so we
    are in sublime text and we're looking at the file named floating before that HTML. So let's go over the structure of this HTML document real quick. We have our regular h1 here just to announce what that is, and then we have a div with four paragraph
    tags and a section tag with some text in it, and the paragraph tags ID p1, p2, p3, p4. If you look at our div section, we styled the div tag, its background to be a certain color. Play video starting at :1:4 and follow transcript1:04 Basically a light
    bluish color, and every single paragraph tag was styled to be 50 pixels wide and 50 pixels tall, and we gave it a nice one pixel border. And just to differentiate between each paragraph box, we gave it a different background color to each one. So
    let's go ahead and take a look at what this looks like in the browser.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
       * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#outer {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  border: 3px solid maroon;

  clear: both;padding:10px;
}

p {
     width: 60%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: auto;
}

#bg {
  background-image: url(downloaded.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<h1>THE BACKGROUND PROPERTY</h1>
<div id="outer">
  It is fun to play with CSS elements.
  
  <p id="inner">
    In this lecture we're going to talk about positioning elements by floating them. Now knowing how to properly float elements is an essential skill to have, and this is partially because most of the UIs today, web UIs today that are made, are made by floating
    the elements. In fact, by the end of this lecture, we're going to create a two column flexible design where the columns will be flexible as we expand and contract the browser. So let's jump into the code editor and see how this works. Okay, so we
    are in sublime text and we're looking at the file named floating before that HTML. So let's go over the structure of this HTML document real quick. We have our regular h1 here just to announce what that is, and then we have a div with four paragraph
    tags and a section tag with some text in it, and the paragraph tags ID p1, p2, p3, p4. If you look at our div section, we styled the div tag, its background to be a certain color. Play video starting at :1:4 and follow transcript1:04 Basically a light
    bluish color, and every single paragraph tag was styled to be 50 pixels wide and 50 pixels tall, and we gave it a nice one pixel border. And just to differentiate between each paragraph box, we gave it a different background color to each one. So
    let's go ahead and take a look at what this looks like in the browser.
  </p>
</div>
```

Check this code, you have added float left that's it's not showing in center. you need to add margin:auto

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using grid for layout?

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#outer {
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid maroon;
}

#bg {
  background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/600/600);
  background-size: cover;
}

.item-a {
  grid-area: header;
}

.item-b {
  grid-area: main;
}

.item-c {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" "main sidebar";
}
```

```html
<h1>THE BACKGROUND PROPERTY</h1>
<div id="outer" class="grid-container">
  <p class="item-a">
    It is fun to play with CSS elements.</p>
  <p id="bg" class="item-b">
  </p>
  <p id="inner" class="item-c">
    In this lecture we're going to talk about positioning elements by floating them. Now knowing how to properly float elements is an essential skill to have, and this is partially because most of the UIs today, web UIs today that are made, are made by floating
    the elements. In fact, by the end of this lecture, we're going to create a two column flexible design where the columns will be flexible as we expand and contract the browser. So let's jump into the code editor and see how this works. Okay, so we
    are in sublime text and we're looking at the file named floating before that HTML. So let's go over the structure of this HTML document real quick. We have our regular h1 here just to announce what that is, and then we have a div with four paragraph
    tags and a section tag with some text in it, and the paragraph tags ID p1, p2, p3, p4. If you look at our div section, we styled the div tag, its background to be a certain color. Play video starting at :1:4 and follow transcript1:04 Basically a light
    bluish color, and every single paragraph tag was styled to be 50 pixels wide and 50 pixels tall, and we gave it a nice one pixel border. And just to differentiate between each paragraph box, we gave it a different background color to each one. So
    let's go ahead and take a look at what this looks like in the browser.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your style with

```
 * {
                    box-sizing: border-box;
                }
                h1 {
                    text-align: center;
                }
                p.full-width {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
                #outer {
                    text-align: center;
                    font-weight: bolder;
                    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, 
        Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
                    border: 3px solid maroon;
                    height: 400px;
                    clear: both;
                    width: 100%;
                    float: left;
                }
                p {
                    width: 50%;
                    float: left;
                    padding: 10px;
                }
                #bg {
                    background-image: url(http://docllpdemo.com/asteroid/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/dummy-man.png);
                    background-size: 65% 50%;
                    min-height: 100%;
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                }
                #inner {
                }
```

and your html with

```
<body>
            <h1>THE BACKGROUND PROPERTY</h1>
            <div id="outer">
    <p class="full-width"> It is fun to play with CSS elements.</p>
                <p id="bg">
                </p>
                <p id="inner">
                    In this lecture we're going to talk about positioning elements by floating 
        them. 
                    Now knowing how to properly float elements is an essential skill to have, 
                    and this is partially because most of the UIs today, web UIs today that are 
        made, 
                    are made by floating the elements. In fact, by the end of this lecture, 
                    we're going to create a two column flexible design where the columns will be 
        flexible 
                    as we expand and contract the browser. So let's jump into the code editor and 
        see how this works. 
               </p></div></body>
        see how this works. 
               </p></div></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with columns my recommendation would to be use grid layout, it is a super tool of sorts, change your #outer element to grid layout with a relative positioning. If you don't want your img to span the entire field remove the  element. Good luck!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

h2{
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
}

#outer {
  position:relative;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(1rem, 1fr) minmax(1rem, 1fr);
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  border: 3px solid maroon;
  
  p{
  z-index:2;
  }
}

#bg {
  background-img: url('downloaded.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

.myImg{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  }
```

```html
<h1>THE BACKGROUND PROPERTY</h1>
  <h2> It is fun to play with CSS elements. </h2>
<div id="outer">

<img src="./downloaded.jpg"  class="myImg"/>

  <div id="bg">
    (empty div to show image)
  </div>
  <div id="inner">
    <p>
      In this lecture we're going to talk about positioning elements by floating them. Now knowing how to properly float elements is an essential skill to have, and this is partially because most of the UIs today, web UIs today that are made, are made by floating
      the elements. In fact, by the end of this lecture, we're going to create a two column flexible design where the columns will be flexible as we expand and contract the browser. So let's jump into the code editor and see how this works. Okay, so we
      are in sublime text and we're looking at the file named floating before that HTML. So let's go over the structure of this HTML document real quick. We have our regular h1 here just to announce what that is, and then we have a div with four paragraph
      tags and a section tag with some text in it, and the paragraph tags ID p1, p2, p3, p4. If you look at our div section, we styled the div tag, its background to be a certain color. Play video starting at :1:4 and follow transcript1:04 Basically a
      light bluish color, and every single paragraph tag was styled to be 50 pixels wide and 50 pixels tall, and we gave it a nice one pixel border. And just to differentiate between each paragraph box, we gave it a different background color to each
      one. So let's go ahead and take a look at what this looks like in the browser.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
  <p id="inner">
    In this lecture we're going to talk about positioning elements by floating them. Now knowing how to properly float elements is an essential skill to have, and this is partially because most of the UIs today, web UIs today that are made, are made by floating
    the elements. In fact, by the end of this lecture, we're going to create a two column flexible design where the columns will be flexible as we expand and contract the browser. So let's jump into the code editor and see how this works. Okay, so we
    are in sublime text and we're looking at the file named floating before that HTML. So let's go over the structure of this HTML document real quick. We have our regular h1 here just to announce what that is, and then we have a div with four paragraph
    tags and a section tag with some text in it, and the paragraph tags ID p1, p2, p3, p4. If you look at our div section, we styled the div tag, its background to be a certain color. Play video starting at :1:4 and follow transcript1:04 Basically a light
    bluish color, and every single paragraph tag was styled to be 50 pixels wide and 50 pixels tall, and we gave it a nice one pixel border. And just to differentiate between each paragraph box, we gave it a different background color to each one. So
    let's go ahead and take a look at what this looks like in the browser.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use bootstrap rows and cols like below

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#outer {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  border: 3px solid maroon;
  height: 400px;
  clear: both;
}

p {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

#bg {
  background-image: url('https://www.holidify.com/images/bgImages/MUMBAI.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

#inner {}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
<h1>THE BACKGROUND PROPERTY</h1>
  <div id="rot" class="row">
    <p class="text-center">
    It is fun to play with CSS elements.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" id="bg" >
    </div>
    <div class="col">
    <p id="inner" >
    In this lecture we're going to talk about positioning elements by floating them. Now knowing how to properly float elements is an essential skill to have, and this is partially because most of the UIs today, web UIs today that are made, are made by floating
    the elements. In fact, by the end of this lecture, we're going to create a two column flexible design where the columns will be flexible as we expand and contract the browser. So let's jump into the code editor and see how this works. Okay, so we
    are in sublime text and we're looking at the file named floating before that HTML. So let's go over the structure of this HTML document real quick. We have our regular h1 here just to announce what that is, and then we have a div with four paragraph
    tags and a section tag with some text in it, and the paragraph tags ID p1, p2, p3, p4. If you look at our div section, we styled the div tag, its background to be a certain color. Play video starting at :1:4 and follow transcript1:04 Basically a light
    bluish color, and every single paragraph tag was styled to be 50 pixels wide and 50 pixels tall, and we gave it a nice one pixel border. And just to differentiate between each paragraph box, we gave it a different background color to each one. So
    let's go ahead and take a look at what this looks like in the browser.
    </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Use Flexbox!

It's a better and intuitive solution than float. You can wrap both `p` in `div` with `flex: 1` which would make them take equal width.

And wrap both `div` with `flex: 1` in a `flex` container.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <style>
    .text-center {
      text-align: center;
    }

    #maroon-border {
      border: 3px solid maroon;
    }

    #flex-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }

    .flex-1 {
      flex: 1;
    }

    #bg {
      background-size: cover;
      background-image: url(https://miro.medium.com/max/1050/1*R9vfWQrF0c223dm3wTTnGQ.jpeg);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="text-center">THE BACKGROUND PROPERTY</h1>

  <div id="maroon-border">
    <p class="text-center">It is fun to play with CSS elements.</p>

    <div id="flex-container">
      <div id="bg" class="flex-1">
        <p></p>
      </div>

      <div class="flex-1">
        <p>
          In this lecture we're going to talk about positioning elements by floating them. Now knowing how to properly
          float elements is an essential skill to have, and this is partially because most of the UIs today, web UIs
          today
          that are made, are made by floating
          the elements. In fact, by the end of this lecture, we're going to create a two column flexible design where
          the
          columns will be flexible as we expand and contract the browser. So let's jump into the code editor and see how
          this works. Okay, so we
          are in sublime text and we're looking at the file named floating before that HTML. So let's go over the
          structure of this HTML document real quick. We have our regular h1 here just to announce what that is, and
          then
          we have a div with four paragraph
          tags and a section tag with some text in it, and the paragraph tags ID p1, p2, p3, p4. If you look at our div
          section, we styled the div tag, its background to be a certain color. Play video starting at :1:4 and follow
          transcript1:04 Basically a light
          bluish color, and every single paragraph tag was styled to be 50 pixels wide and 50 pixels tall, and we gave
          it
          a nice one pixel border. And just to differentiate between each paragraph box, we gave it a different
          background
          color to each one. So
          let's go ahead and take a look at what this looks like in the browser.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```